# Adding array values to std::multimap

Tags: c++, multimap

I am trying to use a multimap with an integer key and values made of array of integers with 2 elements.

```
typedef std::multimap<int,int[2]> reverseHeightMap;
reverseHeightMap container;
```

When I try to add values like this:

```
container.insert( std::pair<int,int[2]>(5,{1,2}) );
```

I get:

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '{'
```

I can't figure if I am failing at defining the data structure or inserting the value, or both. Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't store arrays in containers because one of the requirements for the datatypes stored in STL containers is that they are assignable; arrays are not assignable.

Consider using `std::vector` or `std::array<int, 2>`.

Answer (score 5):

use `std::pair`:

```
typedef std::multimap<int,std::pair<int,int>> reverseHeightMap;
```

**OR :**

encapsulate int[2] in struct :

```
struct int_2
{
    int i_0;
    int i_1;
};

typedef std::multimap<int,int_2> reverseHeightMap;
```